# How do I change a string to a number

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with some code. I need it to return a object like this:

```
{name: "Harry, email: "harry@gmail.com", age: 22}
//age is 22 a number not '22' a string
```

However it is getting returned like this:

```
{name: "Harry, email: "harry@gmail.com", age: '22'}
```

Here is my code

```
function formObj(elems) {
  let form = {};
  for(let elem of elems) {
    let key = elem.id;
    let val = elem.value;
    if(key && val)
      form[key] = val;
  }
  return form;
}

let elements = document.querySelectorAll('form *') 
formObj(elements);
```

```html
<form>
    <label for='name'>name</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' value="Harry"/>

    <label for='email'>email</label>
    <input type='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com"/>

    <label for='age'>age</label>
    <input type='text' id='age' value="22"/>
<form/>
```

Please help out

Comment: convert it by parseInt()

Comment: Set `type=text` to `type=number` like `<input type='number' id='age' value="22"/>` or use parseInt to convert a string into an integer.

Comment: @riorudo  using `type=number` will still make `elem.value` return a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the type of the key is `age`.

```js
function formObj(elems) {
  let form = {};
  for(let elem of elems) {
    let key = elem.id;
    let val = elem.value;
    if(key && val)
      form[key] = key ==="age" ? Number(val) : val;
  }
  console.log(form)
  return form;
}

let elements = document.querySelectorAll('form *') 
formObj(elements);
```

```html
<form>
    <label for='name'>name</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' value="Harry"/>

    <label for='email'>email</label>
    <input type='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com"/>

    <label for='age'>age</label>
    <input type='text' id='age' value="22"/>
<form/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the type of the 'age' input to a number then you should get the desired result, e.g.

```
<input type='number' id='age' value="22" />
```

Comment: No, `elem.value` will still be a string.  `type='number'` just effects how the browser shows the input.